# Drawing unicode-strings with CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, unicode, utf-8, core-graphics

How can I draw unicode respectively utf8 text using the CoreGraphics functions? I can't use the UIKit-functions, because I'm not drawing on the main-thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIKit can now handle per-context drawing on a thread, that should be MUCH simpler than trying to draw the glyphs yourself.

Otherwise I'd look into Core Text.